# Can't connect container docker from Macos

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I'm having problem when connect to container from my local on Macos.

```
docker inspect show: "IPAddress": "172.18.0.2"

docker-machine ip default show: 192.168.99.100
```

I have implemented this command successful:

```
sudo route add 172.18.0.0/16 192.168.99.100
```

But i still can't ping to 172.18.0.2:

```
PING 172.18.0.2 (172.18.0.2): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
```

Who can explain me my fault?

Comment: is the container running ? please show docker ps output

Comment: @itiic: container is running

Comment: When using Docker Machine, you're supposed to connect to the Docker Machine IP address. For example when running a web server in Docker on port 8080, you can access that as 192.168.99.100:8080.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great, i have found out my fault. I can't connect to container from local because i don't run container in VM environment.
In Osx, docker engine will run in VM Linux, so i need to create a VM:

> docker-machine create --driver virtualbox dev

Then, i set some environment variables:

> eval $(docker-machine env dev)

Now, i can build an image docker and run it normally.